# How to load legacy content to sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007

We want to take content from Jive to newly installed sharepoint. How do we do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have to write some custom code to read your content from whatever format your existing CMS exports in and use the SharePoint object model to add it to your SharePoint site.

Comment: You may get lucky with a third party tool like MetaVis or Metalogix if Jive outputs to a format they can handle and Sharepoint can interpret.

Comment: +1 @santosh will probably need to use Jive's REST API to extract the documents and then use the SharePoint API or web services to upload the documents.